# How to read MLComp dataset using python?

Tags: python, machine-learning, dataset, scikit-learn

MLComp dataset have special type of file format what I don't know about. I want to read using python but can't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing to note is that `sklearn` (v0.17.1, as of 24th July 2016), only supports the `DocumentClassification` domain of `mlcomp`.

Supposing you've downloaded the e.g. [WebKB dataset](http://mlcomp.org/datasets/523), which has `id=523`, to `/somewhere/on/your/computer`, you can use the following `sklearn` snippet to load the dataset and train a classifier:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_mlcomp
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB

# Load mlcomp data using sklearn
train_data = load_mlcomp(name_or_id=523, set_='train', mlcomp_root='/somewhere/on/your/computer')
test_data = load_mlcomp(name_or_id=523, set_='test', mlcomp_root='/somewhere/on/your/computer')
# if you had the environment variable `MLCOMP_DATASETS_HOME` set, you wouldn't need to explicitly pass anything to `mlcomp_root`

# `data` is a standard `Bunch` object, so you can now straightforwardly go on and vectorize the dataset,...
vec = CountVectorizer(decode_error='replace')
X_train = vec.fit_transform(train_data.data)
X_test = vec.transform(test_data.data)

# ...train a classifier... 
mnb = MultinomialNB()
mnb.fit(X_train, train_data.target)

# ...and evaluate it.
print('Accuracy: {}'.format(accuracy_score(test_data.target, mnb.predict(X_test))))
```